# help with windows batch scripting basics - execution and calling a separate executable within the script

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd

Newbie to windows scripting. I need help running the .bat file on the command line so I can test it.
I used Text Document as my editor to create the file (opens up also as Notepad).

I performed  file "save as" (ALL FILES). If I open up `cmd`, I can see the file has a .txt extension (myfile.bat.txt). So if I just type in cmd `myfile.bat.txt` the editor opens. I am not sure how to execute this correctly.

As for the logic in my batch script, I am basically logging into a remote directory (already created the net mount) and now I want to:

1. run an executeable file
2. rename some files.

With some research, I written this so far. I have saved it as a .bat file

```
@ echo off
echo This is a batch file to run an executable and rename some files
pause
--run executable file here, just don't know how to do it
x:
cd x:
rename fileA fileB
```

Any help, good tips/practice would be great. Thanks.

Comment: Do you want the program to live independent of your batch? Try `start foo`. If you want the batch to wait until the program finishes, try `foo`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Type in this command in cmd window:

```
rename myfile.bat.txt myfile.bat
```

Now you can run the script by simply invoking:

```
myfile.bat
```

or

```
myfile
```

(provided there's no `myfile.exe` or `myfile.com` in the same directory).

If you need to edit the script further, you can either right click it in Explorer and choose `Edit` or call the editor from the command window:

```
notepad myfile.bat
```

To call a program from the script, simply add its name, if it's in the current directory:

```
someprogram.exe
```

or the name with the path, if it's somewhere else:

```
directory\program.exe
```

or

```
d:\directory\program.exe
```

If the name or the path contain spaces, be sure to enclose the entire name & path string in double quotes:

```
"d:\directory\program name.exe"
```

Comment: @Andy - thanks. The rename worked. I also renamed it to myfile.cmd and it works just as well.

Comment: @jdamae: That's right, they are almost the same. Here you can find how they are different: [Difference between .cmd & .bat files?](http://groups.google.com/group/microsoft.public.win2000.cmdprompt.admin/msg/ad9066638815812c)

Answer (score 0):

you can just type the full name of the program
eg

```
"c:\program dir\program.exe"
```

or you can add the program directory to your path environment variable

```
set PATH=%PATH%;"c:\program dir"
```

and just type the program name

```
program
```

you can also edit your `PATH` variable in windows http://support.microsoft.com/kb/310519

Comment: if I run the program name `program` the notepad app pops up and opens the file. I performed a save file as (All files), but the name of the file still has a .txt extension when viewed in cmd (myfile.bat.txt). so, i'm not sure what is happening.

Comment: ah I see you problem now. Andriy has answered the question but as you are getting into the guts of windows it is always a good idea to be able to see the file extensions. to do this see http://windows.microsoft.com/en-AU/windows-vista/Show-or-hide-file-name-extensions

Answer (score 0):

NOTE: When you save the file in notepad, you want to save it as filename.BAT and select All Files from the second dropdown.  If you don't it still gets saved as a .TXT.

A couple of command to consider:

> CSCRIPT     cscript /? in CMD
>
> START       http://ss64.com/nt/start.html

If you're doing say a VBSCRIPT use CSCRIPT to start it.  If you're trying to execute another BATCH script or an  EXE, use START